# as3: why cursor won't hide?

Tags: actionscript-3, mouse, hide

I've tried everything... it won't hide.

- Obviously tried Mouse.hide()
- tried different player versions (10.2, 10.3, 11)
- tried Mouse.hide() everytime there is a mouse event on the stage
- tried compiling to swf, projector, debug player...

I'm on Mac OS Lion, and I suspect this is the problem, but I'm not sure. As I can't try on another machine. Never had this problem until I upgraded to Lion and CS5.5 at the same time.

I'm out of ideas...

I'm compiling with Flash IDE CS5.5 version 11.5.1.

Any idea is appreciated.

TIA

Update: in fact the only way to hide the cursor is to switch to another application and then come back to the flash projector.

Comment: Sounds like a Flash player bug. Have you tried compiling to Flash 10 or 9?

Comment: Can you get online demos like [this one](http://asgamer.com/2009/quick-tips-as3-hidingshowing-the-mouse) to work?

Comment: None of the online demos I've tried work... the one you posted didn't work either.

Comment: I'm having the same problem for some time now. Seems to me it only happens in webkit browsers (don't have chrome installed at the moment, but doesn't work in safari neither). Because in Firefox it works.

I'm on a mac - snow leopard - compiled through flashbuilder

Comment: Ikno: what about compiling to an app file (projector)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I came back to this problem after some time and the solution in my particular case was this.

```
Mouse.show();
Mouse.hide();
```

It works with the projector player 11.1 in Mac Os 10.7.3.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your wmode option to *window* when embedding the swf.

Comment: Well, the problem is I need it to work on a projector (app/exe) not in a browser.

Comment: It doesn't work for me in Flash Player.app (11.1.x), but does work in Flash Player (10.2.153.1), I'm running Lion as well and targeting flashplayer 10.1 in my builds.

Answer (score 0):

This bug still exists but I've run across a workaround.  This problem only shows up if the application is set up to start in full screen.
Without fullscreen mode on Flash Player the cursor will go away with 
Mouse.hide(); 
Then in Flash Player, select Full Screen from the menu.
Sometimes it takes a couple of times.

In a pinch, this was a very useful discovery, although it is by no means an acceptable workaround for all occasions.

I'm using Flash Player 14 on OSX

Comment: On newer versions of OSX and Air I simply set a 1 second timer to go fullscreen and remove the cursor. It works.